# sudo: apt-get: command not found

Tags: sudo, apt-get

I am trying to run the following command to install some libraries.

`sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config`

It is however returning the following error.

`sudo: apt-get: command not found`

I lack the knowledge to know what is required to install to make this work.

Edit: I was using Mac. `apt-get` is not available to Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apt is not available for MacOS. There are other options such as Homebrew or Macports.

This question has been asked and answered on our Unix sister site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/how-to-install-ap

Answer (score 3):

It depends what version of linux you're using. [Debian based distros](https://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros) use `sudo apt-get <package_name>` while [Fedora based distros](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?basedon=Fedora#simple) use `yum install <package_name>`.

To find out what version you're using execute command `cat /etc/*-release` as stated here: [HowTo: Find Out My Linux Distribution Name and Version](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/)

Comment: Also, on newer Debian systems, it's just `sudo apt install`.  `apt-get` is _supposed_ to still work, but some of the bleeding-edge fringe variants don't include the required symlink.

Comment: OP updated their question to indicate they are on MacOS

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Linux Ubuntu Debian, then use `yum` instead of `apt-get`. Change:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config
```

to

```
sudo yum install graphviz libgraphviz-dev pkg-config
```

That should work.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu use apt, not yum.